# Custom metrics with azure AKS

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to implement custom metrics in my AKS cluster through a metric adapter (https://github.com/Azure/azure-k8s-metrics-adapter).

Following the various examples I was able to deploy the adapter, but not the custom metric, as for example the following:

```
apiVersion: azure.com/v1alpha2
kind: CustomMetric
metadata:
  name: count-ready-pods
  namespace: custom-metrics
spec:
  metric:
    metricName: kube_pod_status_ready
```

The resource results correctly deployed (I did try both in default namespace and in custom-metrics), and looking at the logs of azure-k8s-metrics-adapter´s pod it seems to be processed.

In general I can not retrieve the metric neither from kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" nor a specific hpa (which results into *unknown* current value).

Checking the Application Insights I get these metrics.

My cluster runs kubernetes 1.13.12 .

Does anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong?
How can I check that the generated service principal has effectively access to the needed application insights?

Would anyone suggest to try to implement Prometheus instead? If so, what would be the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What metric are you trying to scale on? It has to be in App Insights which means you need to install the AppInsights client SDK into the code that is running in the container.  You can test that it is in your application insights instance by using: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics. See the [example walkthrough](https://github.com/Azure/azure-k8s-metrics-adapter#custom-metrics).

The metric `kube_pod_status_ready` isn't one that is collected by Application insights that I am aware of.  You are likely looking in your Log analytics workspace and have Container Insights turned on.  This is why you are getting a not found.  That metric is collected by [Container Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview).

For Kubernetes clusters there are generally three layers of metrics you want to collect:

- **Infrastructure** - CPU/Memory/Network/etc of the underlying VM's.  In Azure this is mostly collected by Azure Monitor
- **Platform** - CPU/Memory/Network/etc of each pod and the Kubernetes platform (pods ready/K8s events/etc).  This generally collected by Container Insights if you install it but can also be collected by other third party tools such as Prometheus.
- **Application** - requests per second, latency of request or other custom metrics.  Either by a sdk library that push metrics to a backend such as application insights) or by a pull type mechanism such as Prometheus that polls a metric endpoint on an application.

I would also wonder why you are trying to scale on `kube_pod_status_ready`?  This is in relation to the number pods that are in a `Ready` state, which means they are running.  You more likely want to scale on [cpu, memory](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/), request per second or latency, or if event driven the number of items in a queue (checkout [Keda](https://keda.sh/)).

As for using AppInsights and Containers Insights over [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) (and you will need something like ELK stack to collect logs) or using a third party such as datadog, There are many options and depends on many variables such as costs, operational complexity and comfort level with tools involved. It is an involved conversation that is hard to have on stack-overflow but at it's basics is a hosted vs run your own.

Disclosure: I currently work at Microsoft and built the metric adapter and involved with KEDA project.

Comment: actually it was not so easy to understand which metrics are collected where, and in particular to understand the logic behind the application insights at all. Do I have acced at the metrics collected in the AKS´s insight? I could not find the corresponding key and ID . I did actually create a separate application insight, but looking at the "external" walkthrough I though I could access the resource group in general. About the scaling case I did already implement the CPU metric, and I was exploring other possibilities, e.g. scaling a type of pod related to necessity of another kind.

Comment: for example the only reference to the custom metric you use `performanceCounters/requestsPerSecond` I found on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported, where it belongs to the section **Microsoft.Insights/Components** . While the `kube_pod_status_ready` belongs to **Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters**, which to me looked more reasonable to be collected. In general I got from the walkthroughs that I should be able to access all the metrics collected from Azure Monitor in my resource group. If there is sth wrong with the sp I would like to know.

Comment: @jsturtevant please correct me if I wrong. https://github.com/Azure/azure-k8s-metrics-adapter is able to support request per second based scaling while KEDA is still not as of now?

Comment: This seems out of date, my prometheus metrics are going into appinsights by just adding a few annotations. I can't figure out how to translate them into metrics that can populate a line chart in a dashboard though...

Comment: this is so confusing. AKS has metric server installed. you can see pods running in kube-system and checking for it in `kubectl get --raw '/apis'`. Is that not enough for HPA to be able to collect a custom metric? even though ive created and tested the metric in prometheus i get this `unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: no custom metrics API (custom.metrics.k8s.io) registered`. Surely a config issue on  aks end?

Comment: `AKS has metric server installed. Is that not enough for HPA to be able to collect a custom metric? ` no you must have a custom metric server installed as well.  KEDA provides one and replaces the azure metric adapter. but you must install that on your own.